# Microsoft Flow trigger skipped when item modified multiple times in a minute

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have a Microsoft flow configured on a SharePoint list item update. In that list I have a `Status` column with 5-6 choice values. On each `Status` update a specific mail should be triggered by flow.

When I update the item and wait for `flow` to trigger before next item update, it works perfectly.

But when the item is updated multiple times with in a minute like 1st update(`Status1`) then 2nd update(`Status2`) and so on, the MS Flow triggers only on the last modified item status. The earlier updates are skipped.

Is it the default behavior of Microsoft Flow or I should update the logic.

Answer (score 2):

This has been my experience in several O365 tenants, When the Flow trigger event happens in rapid succession you get this behavior.  Flow seems to run on a 15 minute timer, so when you make multiple edits within 15 minutes you can't be sure what edits the Flow will run on.